# YouTube liveBroadcast Start Time Always in Pacific Timezone

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I would like to schedule a new Live Streaming event using [`youtube.liveBroadcast.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert). I'm using moment.js' `moment.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ")` to get an ISO 8601 timestamp, such as `2017-04-20T11:30:00-0400`. When I execute `insert()` and add the new event, it's always in the Pacific Timezone, not Eastern.

How do I specify which timezone I'd like the Live Event to take place in?

Comment: I have also tried tweaking the `moment.format()` function to include different variations with and without milliseconds and timezone, such as `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SZZ"`. No luck.

Comment: Skimmed through momentjs library docs and found out its [Using Time zones](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/). It says moment().tz(String) is used to change the time zone on an existing moment.

Comment: My moment object is formatted in the correct timezone, and the timezone offset is correct on the YouTube event. It's just... in Pacific.